# MKAnnotationView and passing data to another function

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Actually I'm developing something in my app which displays annotations within my `MKMapView` and those annotations should be clickable and pass a param to a method.
The problem is for now how to pass the parameter to the next function when tapping the disclosure button.
For the formatting of the annotations I use the `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` method to display the disclosure button. But the problem is, how to get values out of the `Annotation` object which is displayed at the moment?

My code for the `Annotation` (only the relevant part):

```
@synthesize coordinate, id, title, subtitle;

+ (id)annotationWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    self = [super init];

    if(nil != self) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And when touching the disclosure button the method `- (void)displayInfo:(NSNumber *) anId;` should be called with handing over `Annotation.id` as the `anId` param.

The disclosure button is generated with that code:

```
   UIButton *disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    dropPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = disclosureButton;
    dropPin.animatesDrop = YES;
    dropPin.canShowCallout = YES;
```

So - the question:
How can I pass that param to the function OR read the `id` of the clicked `Annotation`?

I thought I could do the handling of the tap on disclosureButton either with a selector for UIButton (but - how to pass the id?) or with `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control` (again - how to pass the id?).

I hope you know what I mean and very big thanks in advance for your answers! :)

Comment: Also, in your annotation class, it looks like you've declared a property named "id"?  Highly recommend you name it something else and, as ennuikiller answered, you might not even need it.

Comment: That's a good idea ;-), you're right. Thank you for your helping input :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In calloutAccessoryControlTapped the annotation is available via the view:

```
MKAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
```